# Obtaining property from object sub-class

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm looping over a class object that contains sub-classes to check for and alter null string values:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in contact.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) && prop.GetValue(contact, null) == null)
    {
        prop.SetValue(contact, "");
    }

    if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] props = prop.PropertyType.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propint in props)
        {
            if (propint.PropertyType == typeof(string) && propint.GetValue(prop, null) == null)
            {
                propint.SetValue(prop, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I get the exception "Object Does Not Match Target Type" when calling `propint.GetValue(prop, null)`, I imagine that the reference for the object there isn't correct but i'm not sure what i should put there to reference the sub-class object.

Comment: Was there something wrong with the answer provided to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155924/setting-all-null-object-parameters-to-string-empty)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the instance of the object containing the property you want to access:

```
if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = prop.PropertyType.GetProperties();
    var propValue = prop.GetValue(contact, null);

    foreach (PropertyInfo propint in props)
    {
        if (propint.PropertyType == typeof(string) && propint.GetValue(propValue, null) == null)
        {
            propint.SetValue(propValue, "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This OP is related to a [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155924/setting-all-null-object-parameters-to-string-empty). Please review.

Comment: @Nkosi Your queue solution looks more elegant to me. But this question now appears to me like a duplicate.

Comment: Hence my confusion as to this OP when they asked basically the same thing before. Was not sure if to close this as a duplication as the OP did not indicate if there were problems with the previous question

Comment: @Nkosi voted for closing.